# Adding underscore between strings using GNU sed

Tags: sed, macos

`GNU sed` newbie here...

I have several FASTA files (50K) with headers of the form

```
CYTC2889-12|Homo sapiens
```

and I'd like to place underscores to get

```
CYTC2889-12|Homo_sapiens
```

and write the results to a file.

I'm running on macOS

I've tried

```
 sed -i.bak 's/\s/_/g' file.fas
```

but this gives

```
>CYTC2889-12|Homo _apien_
```

which is close, but incorrect

Any thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can test your command either without the `-i` or restore the bak file if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `sed -i 's/\s/_/g' <path to file>` should do

Comment: @Kate I tried my implementation now (equivalent to that in your comment) without the `-i` flag. It gives `>CYTC2889-12|Homo _apien_`. Not quite what I need, but close.

Comment: You will needcto add `-r` to the sed command to enable the regex. Or replace `\s` with ` `.

Comment: `sed 's/\s/_/' file.fas` is even closer, producing `>CYTC2889-12|Homo _apien`

Comment: `sed -i.bak '' 's/ /_/' file`

Comment: You are *not* using GNU `sed`, but the BSD version of `sed`, otherwise the code would have worked. If you want to replace a whitespace, simply use a whitespace, not `\s`. And @Kate, even if people say they are using GNU `sed`, better avoid superfluous GNU extensions to keep code portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```bash
sed -i'.bak' 's/[[:space:]]/_/g' file.fas
```

I'm using Linux and therefore `GNU sed` and it works with `sed -i 's/\s/_/g'` but if I use `sed --posix -i  's/\s/_/g'` the command will not work.

So in Linux if I want to use posix I have to use:

```bash
sed --posix -i'.bak' 's/[[:space:]]/_/g'  file.fas
```

Comment: Thanks. That works correctly when printing to screen. Trying it now by writing to file. I thought `\s` was a shortcut for `[[:space:]]`, so should give the same output. Why is this the case?

Comment: @compbiostats I think that's about the posix compliant. macOS is POSIX compliant (and two Linux distributions as far as I know). So I think you are not really using `GNU sed` in macOS.

Comment: About "`Trying it now by writing to file`", with `sed -i` should write to file, should not? If I'm not wrong that command should not print to screen.

Comment: Yes, `sed -i` automatically writes to a file (or rather overwrites the existing file)